# Proxy to Jira API

Tags: node.js, api, proxy, jira, angular-cli

I'm having problems with CORS on my Angular 2 app (with CLI/Webpack) and want to set up a Node proxy to redirect my requests using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). I've also set up proxy through the CLI:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

I feel that it's a lot of work to set up end-points for every Jira end-point.

Is it possible to read the request address and just forward it to the Jira server? `http://localhost:4200/api/rest/api/2/issue/<#issueID#>/attachments`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var server = '<JiraServer>';

// TODO: Set up end-point for every URI path???
app.all("/rest/api/2/issue", function(req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: server});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Can this be solved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Really simple!

```
app.all("/*", function(req, res) {
...
}
```